# Evaluation of FilterRules inside a Module

Tags: plotting, optional-arguments

I'm trying to customize a plot function according to this code

```
myPlot[fun_, opts_: OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{cm = 72/2.54},
   Show[fun, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]
   ];
myPlot[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], ImageSize -> 2 cm]
```

To make this works (try to substitute `2 cm` with 100 for instance) I have to ask `FilterRules` to look for `Plot` options instead of `Show` options. This sound strange to me but is not the main problem. The main problem is that `cm` is defined within the module and it is not evaluate properly when passed to `ImageSize` option.

Could someone suggest a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: To the non-main problem, evaluate `Options[Show]` and you'll see why you don't filter any

Comment: @JasonB: It gives me an empty list, though ImageSize is a Show option. See now your comment on Module vs Block and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation,

> `Show` allows any option that can be applied to graphics to be given.

But if you try to look at the options specific to `Show` you find none,

```
Options[Show]
(* {} *)
```

So you should use `Options[Graphics]` instead.

And to the main problem, it's a scoping thing. [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) replaces all instances of cm with `cm$232494` or some other random number. This is one case where you need [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) instead.  I recommend reading Leonid's post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/9490) for a great treatment of the various scoping constructs.

```
myPlot[fun_, opts_: OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{cm = 72/2.54}, 
   Show[fun, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]];
myPlot[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], ImageSize -> 18 cm]
```

[image]

One important caveat is that if you are defining `myPlot` as an exported function in a package, then it is necessary to export `cm`, otherwise it is in the `` mypackage`Private`cm `` context. Thanks to Kuba for pointing this out.